# Painting on a listview disables the redraw on listview items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, gdi+

What's the reason for this?

I override OnPaintBackground and draw a string. It doesn't show up until I call this in the constructor:

```
this.SetStyle ( ControlStyles.UserPaint, true );
```

But then I don't see the items in the listview.

Why and how to solve this?

EDIT: code

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground ( PaintEventArgs pevent )
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground ( pevent );

        // Create string to draw.
        String drawString = "76";

        // Create font and brush.
        Font drawFont = new Font ( "Arial", 36 );
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush ( Color.Blue );

        // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
        PointF drawPoint = new PointF ( 150.0F, 150.0F );

        // Draw string to screen.
        pevent.Graphics.DrawString ( drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint );

        //pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle ( drawBrush, this.ClientRectangle );
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Are you calling base.OnPaintBackground()?  Can you post the code from your override?

Comment: What are the values of the following properties and styles?

 - ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer
 - ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
 - ListView.OwnerDraw

Comment: @Sheng, nothing else. I just added UserPaint, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the last thread about this subject, `OnPaint()` and `UserPaint` don't work with ListView. The painting is handled by the underlying control and cannot be intercepted in that fashion. This is different to other Controls

So, when `ControlStyles.UserPaint` is `true`, the underlying control is not told to redraw itself. Instead, all drawing is routed to the `OnPaintBackground()` and `OnPaint()` methods, which -- as you have found -- do nothing.

There are two ways to do what you asked (the second is better than the first):

First way: Intercept the `WM_PAINT`, do the base processing, and then draw onto the listview. Something like this:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case 0x0F: // WM_PAINT
                this.HandlePaint(ref m);
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandlePaint(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics()) {
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
            g.DrawString("Some text", new Font("Tahoma", 13),
                SystemBrushes.ControlDark, this.ClientRectangle, sf);
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives repaint problems when what you draw is outside the area that the listview thinks holds the control's contents -- it doesn't trigger paint events.

Second manner: Intercept the CustomDraw notification (this is *not* the same as OwnerDraw), and listen for the `CDDS_POSTPAINT` stage. In that stage you can safely draw onto the list view. You can look at the code of [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) to see how it is done.

You could also just save yourself a lot of bother and use an ObjectListView directly :)

Comment: Thanks Grammarian, I will switch to your listview.

Comment: Btw I just switched to your list view, which is great. But ran into a cast exception for mouse hit testing, although I don't use those events in code.