# Listview wont display any data when using SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to add a custom message to the background of a listview when there is no data to display.  I have turned on the UserPaint flag via the call below which has given me exactly what I want.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
```

However, this then disables all of the Item and SubItem drawing for the entire ListView. I am only assuming that with this set to true, I am now responsible for drawing all items myself (I could be wrong).

If I am correct, does anyone have a tutorial on how to custom draw list items manually, or give me some examples as I am very new to working with messages and would love to get my head around it all.

Below is my code for drawing my custom message via the OnPaint method:

```
        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
            Dim MessageFont As Font = _EmptyMessageFont
            Dim MessageColour As Color = _EmptyMessageColour
            Dim MessageText As String = _EmptyMessageString

            If Not Me.Items.Count > 0 Then
                Dim flags As TextFormatFlags
                Dim rec As New Rectangle(Me.Location.X + 2, Me.Location.Y + 2, Me.Width - 4, Me.Height - 4)
                flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.SingleLine
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, MessageText, MessageFont, rec, MessageColour, flags)
            End If

            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        End Sub
```

Not sure how to add code in this method to handle the normal drawing of list items.

Comment: Try overriding the `OnPaint` handler and call `Paint` of each item, i'll try to throw in some code in the next few minutes. But first, tell us how you paint your `custom` message. Maybe a more prudent course would be to disable the ListView and Shadow it with a Label of the same size, when there is no Data?

Comment: the LV will supports a BG image. perhaps you could display a message as an image rather than taking over all the drawing?

Comment: Ok poked around on SO for a while, and found the answer i was preparing to tinker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621044/painting-on-a-listview-disables-the-redraw-on-listview-items

Comment: Thanks MrPaulch.  I have updated my post to include my OnPaint event code.  I checked your link that you posted, but it doesn't make much sense to me with the CDDS_POSTPAINT as I am not that familiar with notification intercepting.