# Override OnPaintBackground of listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to have listview with a special background and I want to override the onpaintbackground method but this method won't be called unless I enable UserPaint using SetStyle method. But the problem is that when I enable it nothing will be drawn and everything must be written. Is there anyway to call native methods to draw and paint the listview and just override OnPaintBackground method?

Comment: You can set the LV to owner-draw and code only the background drawing. All other events and things can be set to use the default. Note that this is done on a __per item__ basis so to create a background for the __whole__ LV is not exactly simple or nice.. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282743/listview-with-background-image-and-custom-cell-colors/30284799?s=1|2.0485#30284799) for an example which I would not recommend, really..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Or turn on the LVS_EX_TRANSPARENTBKGND extended style flag.

Comment: This answer has the reason why you cannot do this, and how to get around it :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1621275/106008